# Bitcoin-Qt locks up

Tags: bitcoin-core

During Initial Sync BitCoin-QT to lock-up and cause Debian Wheezy to crash and reboot...no error message.  How do I fix this issue?  Subsequent execution of client software has same result.

Comment: Do you mean that the Bitcoin-Qt client crashed, or that your whole computer crashed?

Comment: Immediately? After running for some time? What do you mean by 'lock up'? In any case, if it reboots your system my guess is hardware failure (perhaps overheating?)